# Issue with stored procedure returning no results

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, full-text-search

I have the following MySQL procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ESOLUTIONS`.`getPlatformByAttribute`(
    IN attributeName VARCHAR(255),
    IN startRow INT
)
BEGIN
    SELECT
        GUID,
        PLATFORMNAME,
    MATCH (PLATFORMNAME, PLATFORMDESCRIPTION)
    AGAINST (+attributeName WITH QUERY EXPANSION)
    FROM ESOLUTIONS.PLATFORMS
    WHERE MATCH (PLATFORMNAME, PLATFORMDESCRIPTION)
    AGAINST (+attributeName IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    AND PLATFORMSTATUS = 'ACTIVE'
    LIMIT startRow, 20;
END
```

This should return at least 1 row, as there are 4 with the "platformname" of "platform", and that is what I'm basing my query with. Here is the table:

```
-- ESOLUTIONS.PLATFORMS definition

CREATE TABLE `PLATFORMS` (
  `GUID` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `PLATFORMNAME` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `PLATFORMSTATUS` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
  `PLATFORMDESCRIPTION` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`GUID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `GUID` (`GUID`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `PLATFORMS_PLATFORMNAME_IDX` (`PLATFORMNAME`,`PLATFORMDESCRIPTION`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

I've run optimize and analyze and neither of them are having any effect. Any ideas?

Comment: Provide sample data which allows to reproduce your issue according to [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.